statistical method for analysis of multiple related variables affecting 1/2 outcomes
I am going to abstract this question to conceal my actual research contents, but I am an absolute noob in statistical analysis, and I would like to learn more from the gods of this website.
I am currently doing research on whether number of hours of sleep, whether they are sick or not, and the number of hours of work that they carry out during the day, and how that may lead to the development of depression over the span of 1 year. Another outcome would be them developing violent tendencies as a result of the depression.
what I want to investigate is the factors' independent effect on each of the outcomes, accounting for the potential confounding(as depression is a well-known predisposing factor to violent tendencies, but I would like to see whether the factors will lead to violent tendencies even without depression).
I was originally debating between the use of MANCOVA and multiple linear regression, but I am not sure how I should approach this. any other suggestion towards the methodology used. Thank you very much in advance for those  who are willing to help me with this. It means a lot to me as a learning experience.

What data have you got? Particularly, do you have multiple observations of the same people? How many repeats?   Also, if you are really an "absolute noob" then, I'm sorry, but this analysis may be beyond you. (But people use "noob" in different ways, so, maybe you are not that new.)

@PeterFlom I currently have data from a psychiatric hospital from the past 10 years of patients coming in and out, and the sample size is around 300-400. I wouldn't call myself an absolute noob(its my second or so time performing research and analysis), but I've never had to do multivariate analysis to this scale. The actual set of data contains around 10-15 independent variables affecting the outcome of the patients. Please give me advice in any way you desire.

Combining your question and your comment, I think there are two ways you could go: A nonlinear multilevel model, where the dependent variable is "developed depression" (yes/no) or a survival analysis with time varying covariates where the DV is time to development of depression (and it is, I think, interval censored).
If relatively few people developed depression, I would go with the first, because there would be a lot of censoring and that decreases the power of survival analysis. But if there are a reasonable number of people with depression, then survival analysis might be better, as it is probably going to be more powerful, since it distinguishes people who got depressed after a month from those who got depressed at 11 months.
